# Vector Troubles in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I am currently working on a project that deals with a vector of objects of a People class. The program compiles and runs just fine, but when I use the debugger it dies when trying to do anything with the PersonWrangler object. I currently have 3 different classes, one for the person, a personwrangler which handles all of the people collectively, and a game class that handles the game input and output.

Edit: My basic question is to understand why it is dying when it calls outputPeople. Also I would like to understand why my program works exactly as it should unless I use the debugger. The outputPeople function works the way I intended that way.

Edit 2: The callstack has 3 bad calls which are:

1. std::vector >::begin(this=0xbaadf00d)
2. std::vector >::size(this=0xbaadf00d)
3. PersonWrangler::outputPeople(this=0xbaadf00d)

Relevant code:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void gameLoop();
    void menu();
    void setStatus(bool inputStatus);
    bool getStatus();
    PersonWrangler* hal;
private:
    bool status;
};
```

which calls outputPeople where it promptly dies from a baadf00d error.

```
void Game::menu()
{
    hal->outputPeople();
}
```

where hal is an object of PersonWrangler type

```
class PersonWrangler
{
public:
    PersonWrangler(int inputStartingNum);
    void outputPeople();  
    vector<Person*> peopleVector;
    vector<Person*>::iterator personIterator;  
    int totalPeople;
};
```

and the outputPeople function is defined as

```
void PersonWrangler::outputPeople()
{
    int totalConnections = 0;
    cout << " Total People:" << peopleVector.size() << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < peopleVector.size();i++)
    {
        sort(peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.begin(),peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.end());
        peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.erase( unique (peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.begin(),peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.end()),peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.end());
        peopleVector[i]->outputPerson();
        totalConnections+=peopleVector[i]->connectionsVector.size();
    }
    cout << "Total connections:" << totalConnections/2 << endl;
}
```

Where hal is initialized

```
Game::Game()
{
    PersonWrangler* hal = new PersonWrangler(inputStartingNum);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using so many pointers? Raw pointer use is discouraged in C++.

Comment: Is you object hal of type PersonWrangler* a valid value?

Comment: How, exactly, is the debugger dying? What's the exact error message? What line is it dying on? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Connections vector is a int vector that each person object has.

Comment: To rep_movsd's point, can you show where you initialize hal? Nothing in your posting shows it being initialized.

Comment: @Billy I wish people would not say things like "is there any reason you're using so many pointers? Raw pointer use is discouraged in C++" without qualification.

Comment: @Neil: Good point. Let me change my statement to "raw pointer use is discouraged in C++. If you can use an automatic variable you should use that instead, and if you cannot, you should use a smart pointer class like shared_ptr or scoped_ptr". Better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0xBAADFOOD` is a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) to alert you to the fact that you're dealing with uninitialized memory. From the stack trace, we see that `this` in `PersonWrangler::outputPeople` is invalid. Thus `hal` doesn't point to a valid `PersonWrangler` (that is, assuming frame 4 is a call to `Game::menu`). To resolve this sort of thing yourself, step through the code, starting at `Game::Game()`, examining `Game::hal` as you go, to see what might be going wrong.

In `Game::Game`, `hal` is a local variable that [shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `Game::hal`. When `Game::Game` exits, this `hal` goes out of scope and leaks memory, while `Game::hal` remains uninitialized. What you want is:

```
Game::Game()
{
    hal = new PersonWrangler(inputStartingNum);
}
```

Debuggers fill uninitialized memory with magic numbers to make it easier to spot errors. In a  production build, memory isn't filled with anything in particular; the content of uninitialized memory is undefined, and might hold valid values. This is why a production build might not fail when a debug build will.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize `hal` to point to an actual PersonWrangler object?

Creating a pointer does not point it at an actual object unless you do it explicitly. You probably want to either pass a PersonWrangler to your Game at construction time, or have the Game constructor create a PersonWrangler using `new`. If you choose the latter, make sure to `delete` your PersonWrangler somewhere, probably in the Game deconstructor.